# Existence of an integer $i$ such that $i$ and $i+1$ are both squares mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

Let $p$ be a prime $\ne 2,5$

Prove $\exists i\le 9$ such that $(\frac{i}{p})=(\frac{i+1}{p})=1$ where $(.)$ is the Legendre symbol.

I tried to use the Euler formula $(\frac{a}{p})\equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \mod p$ 
but it leads nowhere.

Thank you for any hints.

### Edit

We should also have $p\ne 3$ for the statement above to be correct as 2 is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$.

Comment: It's a small correction but I think $p$ has to be greater than $3$ for that statement to be true. Then, for thoses cases, use the hint provided by @lulu

Comment: Thanks @pm2595, I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:  I assume you intend $i\in \{1,2,\cdots, 9\}$, else $i=0$ is a cheap example.

Hint:  argue that at least one of $2,5,10$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$.